# jQuery callback plus js function

Tags: jquery

Hi I am having some trouble combining a js function with a jQuery function.  The code below works, but as you might have guessed, I am hoping to fade first, then change the HTML, then fade back in.

```
function updateit(a) {
    $("#monthlyHead").fadeOut(100);
    $("#monthlyText").fadeOut(100);

    if (a == 1) {
        $("#monthlyHead").html(headone);
        $("#monthlyText").html(textone);
    }
    else if (a == 2) {
        $("#monthlyHead").html(headtwo);
        $("#monthlyText").html(texttwo);
    }

    $("#monthlyHead").fadeIn(900);
    $("#monthlyText").fadeIn(900);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateIt(a){
    $("#monthlyHead,#monthlyText").fadeOut(100,function(){
          if (a == 1) {
              $("#monthlyHead").html(headone);
              $("#monthlyText").html(textone);
           } else if (a == 2) {
             $("#monthlyHead").html(headtwo);
             $("#monthlyText").html(texttwo);
           }

        $(this).fadeIn(900);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fadeOut, fadeIn, and all the jQuery animation methods take an optional 'callback' argument that gets run when the animation completes.  That's what you should use here.  So:

```
$("#monthlyHead").fadeOut(100, function() {
    if (a == 1) {
        $("#monthlyHead").html(headone);
    }
    else {
        $("#monthlyHead").html(headtwo);
    }
    $("#monthlyHead").fadeIn(900);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/VAV44/)** here

Try this

```
function updateit(a) {

    $("#monthlyHead").fadeOut(100, function () {
         if (a == 1) {
            $("#monthlyHead").html(headone);
        } else if (a == 2) {
            $("#monthlyHead").html(headtwo);
        }

    }).fadeOut(900);

    $("#monthlyText").fadeOut(100, function () {
         if (a == 1) {
            $("#monthlyText").html(textone);
        } else if (a == 2) {
            $("#monthlyText").html(texttwo);
        }

    }).fadeOut(900);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the following construction?

```
$(selector).fadeOut(100, function(){
   $(selector2).html(text);
   $(selector).fadeIn(900);
});
```